# Mclust in R: How to output cluster centers

Tags: r, text-mining, mclust

I'm currently using RStudio for doing text mining on Support tickets, clustering them by their description (freetext). For this, I compare kmeans to EM algorithm. I prepared the data with the tm package, and now I try do apply clustering algorithms to the data matrix.

With the kmeans() function, I can use following Code snippet to Output the 5 most frequent Terms in text Clusters (kmeans21):

```
> for (i in 1:num_cluster) {
     cat(paste("cluster ", i, ": ", sep = ""))
     s <- sort(kmeans21$centers[i, ], decreasing = T)
     cat(names(s)[1:5], "\n")
 }
```

Until now, I couldnt find a function to do the same within the mclust package. My data has the following Format:

```
> bic21 <- MclustBIC(m1, G=21)
> emmodel21 <- summary(bic21, data = m1)
```

With the command

```
> emmodel21$classification
```

I can see the Cluster for each supportticket, but is there also the possibility to Output the most frequent Terms like in the first Code block for kmeans?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try

```
summary(mod1, parameters = TRUE)
```

Just tried the same example in the link

```
library(mclust)
data(diabetes)
X <- diabetes[,-1]
BIC <- mclustBIC(X)
mod1 <- Mclust(X, x = BIC)
summary(mod1, parameters = TRUE)
```

Comment: For more info see the link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/vignettes/mclust.html

Answer (score 0):

Slightly altering the first example in the vignette:

```
data(diabetes)
X <- diabetes[,-1]
mod <- mclust(X)
means <- mod$parameters$means
```

The means object is now a matrix containing the means of the clusters.